# How can I get the length of a model when I create an instance of it in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a model class named Project, and I wanted to use the length of the Project models.

I mean when I create an instance of Project, if there are 10 instances, I wanna set the default value of order field is the length of the Project model.

How can I get the current length of the model?

this is my models.py code for Project model

in **models.py**

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isPublic=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    content=models.TextField()
    detailUrl=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # where to upload
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = createFileName, help_text="The recommended size of the images are 1x1")
    time=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    view=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.order=models.IntegerField(default=0) # this works fine but this isn't what I want
        self.order=models.IntegerField(default=len(Project.objects.all())) 
        # this is what I want but it gives me no response without emitting errors.
```

Comment: `Project._base_manager.count()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`default=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) can be a callable that you use to determine the default value. For example:

```
def default_project_order():
    return Project._base_manager.count()

class Project(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order=models.IntegerField(default=default_project_order)
    isPublic=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    content=models.TextField()
    detailUrl=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # where to upload
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = createFileName, help_text="The recommended size of the images are 1x1")
    time=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    view=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I edited my post. What I wanted to say was how to use the status of the model as creating an instance of it. I changed order variable into length. Can you check it out again? Thank you.

Comment: @umi0410: this is the length (number of records in the database). `len(qs)` and `qs.count()` are equivalent, but `.count()` does the counting at the database side, which is more efficient.

Comment: oh, then you were right. I found out what you said, "default can be a callable". Thank you.